# Changing the way params comes in from the form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Right now I'm using a hidden field tag to get the plan_id. But when I use I binding.pry it's nested in the accounts hash. In order to get to the plan_id I have to do this `params[:accounts][:plan_id]` when I simply want to do this `params[:plan_id]`. How can I achieve this? Here is my code.

```
   <label>
     <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: 1 %>
     <%= f.submit "Select", class: "button-big reverse-blue" %>
   </label>
```

Here is my params look like

```
 { "account"=>{"name"=>"something", "plan_id"=>"1"}, "stripe_card_token"=>"", "card_number"=>"", "card_holder"=>"", "controller"=>"accounts", "action"=>"create"}
```

I want them to look like this

```
{"account"=>{"name"=>"something"}, "plan_id"=>"1", "stripe_card_token"=>"", "card_number"=>"", "card_holder"=>"", "controller"=>"accounts", "action"=>"create"}
```

Again. I'd like to access the plan Id by simply typing this `params[:plan_id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `hidden_field_tag`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :plan_id, 1 %>
```

Comment: Sorry it's not a hidden_field_tag. It's a f.hidden_field

Comment: Ehm, I'm suggesting you make it a `hidden_field_tag` :/

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: I'm going to post another question in a minute I think you may be able to help. Thanks for help today so far

Comment: No problem. If I can help, I do it